# How to get jwt token from url in react using react-router-dom v6

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, jwt

I am implementing forgot and reset password feature in my mern app. Everything is working in backend when I check with backend . I implement following logic/step at frontend.

1. user enter his email in form and submit
2. At backend jwt token gets created and if user exist in db then user will get mail with the link to reset password (`http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI2Mjg5OTEyYjQxNDBmYTczNjgwZGJiNzciLCJpYXQiOjE2NTMzOTI1NDEsImV4cCI6MTY1MzM5MzQ0MX0.btK8fNq80C0QRPjPErAOm2hVjgsVvCbU7vhrYM4kT_8)` like this .

At frontend I have written route like this `<Route path='/resetpassword/:token' element={<ResetPassword />} />`

But when i hit this route I am getting `Page cant be found` error . But if I try with `http://localhost:3000/resetpassword/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9` (without any dot in token) its working . Previously same logic worked with react-router-v5 but not working with react-router-v6

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with your server config.

Add this to your webpack dev server config:

```
  historyApiFallback: {
    disableDotRule: true
  }
```

Comment: I dont know exactly where I have to add it in vite react app . @arnaspdk Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: What is your bundler?

Comment: got it now. It worked when I use vite-plugin-rewrite-all npm package